# Error when creating response header AWS CloudFront policy with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to replicate, using Terraform, the configuration in the image. It is part of a response header CloudFront policy. [image]

This is my code:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_response_headers_policy" "example" {
  name    = "MyPolicy"

  cors_config {
    access_control_allow_credentials = false

    access_control_allow_headers {
      items = []
    }

    access_control_allow_methods {
      items = ["GET", "HEAD", "PUT", "POST", "PATH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
    }

    access_control_allow_origins {
      items = ["*"]
    }

    access_control_expose_headers {
      items = ["*"]
    }

    origin_override = true
  }

  # more stuff...
 
}
```

But I get this error:

> Error: updating CloudFront Response Headers Policy
> (69ff4b65-a470-472a-8bb1-e412b42cb39f): InvalidParameter: 2 validation
> error(s) found. │ - missing required field,
> UpdateResponseHeadersPolicyInput.ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.CorsConfig.AccessControlAllowHeaders.Items.
> │ - missing required field,
> UpdateResponseHeadersPolicyInput.ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.CorsConfig.AccessControlAllowHeaders.Quantity.

It seems Terraform doesn't like an empty array. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Which provider version is this?

Comment: I'm using version 5.8.0

Comment: Ok, can you try with `items = [""]`? Also, does that mean you are allowing all headers or none?

Comment: Not related but I think terraformer can help, use it to create terraform code.